# How to display SVG on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, svg

So I've done the hardest part of actually displaying the SVG with the help of Giovanni Gatto(credit: https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/tkinter-shows-an-svg-file/)

I've modified the code to fit my needs, but after implementation, rather than it assigning the SVG to each button individually, it will only display it on the last button on the frame.

I can create a function for each button, but that would be inefficient, what is the best way to approach this?

**Import**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
from io import BytesIO
import PIL.Image
```

**Function**
This is within a class, but for readability convenience here is the function that converts converts.

```
def imgToButton(image):
   global img
   svgfile = svg2rlg(image)
   bytespng = BytesIO()
   renderPM.drawToFile(svgfile, bytespng, bg=0x393A4C, fmt="PNG")
   img = PIL.Image.open(bytespng)
   img = img.resize((20, 20), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
   img.image = img
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
   return img
```

**Object**

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(self.labelframe1)
self.button1.configure(activebackground='#393a4c', activeforeground='#000000', background='#393a4c', font='{Century Gothic} 13 {bold}')
self.button1.configure(foreground='#000000', highlightbackground='#393a4c', highlightcolor='#393a4c', highlightthickness='100')
self.button1.configure(justify='center', text='')
self.button1.configure(image=imgToButton("/Users/giuseppemarziano/Desktop/Scripts/Personal Projects/Auto Click GM/ACGM 0.04/ACGM Images/plus.svg"))
self.button1.place(height='25', relx='0.0', rely='0.0', width='25', x='5', y='3')
self.button1.bind('<1>', self.addSeq, add='+')
```

Apologies for using the full path, I am currently on an M1 MacBook Pro, which is an absolute nightmare for Python or coding in general

Ideally, I would like for each button to call the function, asign the image to the button, then repeat the process, rather than not doing that

I have also used `self.button1.update()`, but that still yields the same result.

FYI: if you are struggling with low-res .PNG images on Tkinter and want to use .SVG for high-res smaller images, you can implement this code to display an SVG image on a button or any object, all you need to do is make sure you are able to `import svglib` and `import reportlab`, you should already have pillow, if not: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: how do you create buttons? Do you use `for`-loop? Do you use `lambda` in loop? It may need something like `lambda x=img:func(x)` instead of `lambda:func(img)`

Comment: I just created them invidually, the only thing that I find difficult with loops is assigning different images to each, I can try to append them actually and try take that route, would still be cleaner than 7 functions

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `global img` in function - this way you replace last image with new image and it can make problem - because bug in PhotoImage may remove previous image from memory. You should keep all image on list. So you should use global list `all_images` and keep it with `all_images.append(img)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but problem can be bug in `PhotoImage` which removes it when it is assigned to local variable.

Normally you could assign `PhotoImage to global variable or to other class

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
img.photo = photo
```

not `img.image = PIL.Image.open(bytespng)`

But you run it many times so you assign new image to the same variable so previous image is removed from variable and then bug in PhotoImage removes it from memory.

You should keep all `PhotoImage` in different variables or on list

```
all_photoimages = []   # global list 

def imgToButton(image):

   svgfile = svg2rlg(image)
   bytespng = BytesIO()
   renderPM.drawToFile(svgfile, bytespng, bg=0x393A4C, fmt="PNG")
   
   img = PIL.Image.open(bytespng)
   img = img.resize((20, 20), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
   
   photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
   #img.photo = photo
   all_photoimages.append(photo)  # keep in global list
   
   return photo
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @TheLizzard noticed in comment you can also assign `PhotoImage` to `Button` and then you don't need list `all_photoimages` because every `PhotoImage` will be assigned to different `Button`

And this method seems cleaner - because `imgToButton` doesn't have to use external list.

```
  # get photoimage 
  img = imgToButton(...) 

  # use it with button
  self.button1.configure(image=img)

  # assign to button to resolve problem with bug
  self.button1.tk_img = img

# -----

def imgToButton(image):

   svgfile = svg2rlg(image)
   bytespng = BytesIO()
   renderPM.drawToFile(svgfile, bytespng, bg=0x393A4C, fmt="PNG")
   
   img = PIL.Image.open(bytespng)
   img = img.resize((20, 20), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
   
   return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Comment: You that as long as you keep a reference to the image returned by `imgToButton`, the code will run fine. Instead you can use `img = imgToButton(...)`, `self.button1.configure(image=img)` and lastly `self.button1.tk_img = img`

Comment: @TheLizzard yes this other method to keep it. You could describe it in answer. OP will have two methods to choose.

Comment: Do you want to update your answer with the second method? For some reason I am feeling lazy today :D

Comment: @TheLizzard OK, I added your version.

Comment: Thx. You saved me the trouble of writing my own answer